# Text Component won't render after a certain height

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

With React Native's Text components, there is a certain height (about 500-600 lines) after which a text view just stops rendering on iOS devices. This doesn't appear to be an issue on Android.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

const text = ".\n".repeat(600)

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
      }}>
        <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Text>{text}</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is demonstrated by changing the value of the repeat between 200 (where it renders correctly) and 600 where a blank screen is rendered.

What are the best workarounds to this issue? I'm assuming this must be an issue with iOS's UILabel object, since the issue is platform dependent.